# Getting random integer without 3 set bits in a row

Tags: algorithm, random, bit-manipulation

Is there a performant way to generate an unbiased 64b random integer without 3 set bits in a row, assuming a fast-and-unbiased input PRNG? I *don't* care about 'wasting bits' of the input source.

That is, something better than the naive rejection-sampling approach:

```c
uint64_t r;
do {
    r = get_rand_64();
} while (r & (r >> 1) & (r >> 2));
```

...which "works", but is very slow. It looks like it's iterating ~187x on average or so.

One possibility I've explored is roughly:

```c
bool p2 = get_rand_bit();
bool p1 = get_rand_bit();
uint64_t r = (p1 << 1) | p2;
for (int i = 2; i < 64; i++) {
    bool p0 = (p1 && p2) ? false : get_rand_bit();
    r |= p0 << i;
    p2 = p1;
    p1 = p0;
}
```

...however, this is still slow. Mainly because using this approach the entire calculation is bit-serial. EDIT: and it's also biased. Easiest to see with a 3-bit integer - 0b011 occurs 1/8th of the time, which is wrong (should be 1/7th).

I've tried doing various parallel fixups, but haven't been able to come up with anything unbiased. It's useful to play around with 4-bit integers first - e.g. setting all bits involved in a conflict to random values ends up biased, and drawing out the Markov chain for 4 bits makes that obvious

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What if you did `r & 010101010101010101....` to force every other bit to 0?  Just a thought with zero analysis behind it.  I do realize it eliminates half the answer space at step 1, but is the other half being unbiased usable?

Comment: Something better than rejection sampling would probably require a mathematical understanding of the set that you are trying to sample from. To that end, you can check out https://oeis.org/A003726

Comment: @DaveS - eliminating 1/2 the answer space in an unbiased manner might be acceptable; eliminating all but 1/2**32 of the answer space in a biased manner is not.

Comment: Something that covered the output space with limited bias, and which cheaply outputted for each random number both the number and the sampling weight, might be acceptable.

Comment: @JohnColeman - hm. Good point about OEIS. Now to dig into Tribonacci numbers...

Comment: Speaking of Markov chains, there's a fast MCMC method that probably mixes reasonably well.

Comment: What level of improvement in performance would be acceptable for you?

Comment: @TylerH - David's answer appears fast enough in practice (though improvements are always welcome). Read: is no longer the dominating function in the flamegraph :-)

Comment: <mild rant>performance optimization no longer being on topic for Stack Exchange is about par for the course, as are people asking 'clarifying' comments simply so they can delete the question</mild rant>. Thank you David for answering the question well before the deletionists could show up, on an unrelated note. This mild rant is not about you.

Comment: "How can X be made faster" absolutely _is_ fact-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I optimized the lexicographic decoder, resulting in a four-fold speedup relative to my previous answer. There are two new ideas:

- Use the one-to-one correspondence implied by the recurrence T(n) = T(k−1) T(n−k) + T(k−2) T(n−k−1) + T(k−2) T(n−k−2) + T(k−3) T(n−k−1) to avoid working one bit at a time;
- Cache the small words without 111 in addition to the recurrence values, incurring an L1 cache hit to save a number of arithmetic operations.

```c
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

enum { kTribonacci14 = 5768 };

static uint64_t g_tribonacci[65];

static void InitTribonacci(void) {
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 65; i++) {
    g_tribonacci[i] =
        i < 3 ? 1 << i
              : g_tribonacci[i - 1] + g_tribonacci[i - 2] + g_tribonacci[i - 3];
  }
  assert(g_tribonacci[14] == kTribonacci14);
}

static uint16_t g_words_no_111[kTribonacci14];

static void InitCachedWordsNo111(void) {
  unsigned i = 0;
  for (unsigned word = 0; word < ((unsigned)1 << 14); word++) {
    if ((word & (word >> 1) & (word >> 2)) == 0) {
      assert(i < kTribonacci14);
      g_words_no_111[i++] = (uint16_t)word;
    }
  }
  assert(i == kTribonacci14);
}

static bool CaseNo111(uint64_t *restrict result, unsigned *restrict n,
                      uint64_t *restrict index, unsigned left_n,
                      unsigned right_n) {
  uint64_t left_count = g_tribonacci[left_n];
  uint64_t right_count = g_tribonacci[right_n];
  uint64_t product = left_count * right_count;
  if (*index >= product) {
    *index -= product;
    return false;
  }
  *result = (*result << left_n) + g_words_no_111[*index / right_count];
  *n = right_n;
  *index %= right_count;
  return true;
}

static void Append(uint64_t *result, uint64_t bit) {
  *result = (*result << 1) + bit;
}

static uint64_t DecodeNo111(unsigned n, uint64_t index) {
  assert(0 <= n && n <= 64);
  assert(index < g_tribonacci[n]);
  uint64_t result = 0;
  while (n > 14) {
    assert(g_tribonacci[n] == g_tribonacci[12] * g_tribonacci[n - 13] +
                                  g_tribonacci[11] * g_tribonacci[n - 14] +
                                  g_tribonacci[11] * g_tribonacci[n - 15] +
                                  g_tribonacci[10] * g_tribonacci[n - 14]);
    if (CaseNo111(&result, &n, &index, 12, n - 13)) {
      Append(&result, 0);
    } else if (CaseNo111(&result, &n, &index, 11, n - 14)) {
      Append(&result, 0);
      Append(&result, 1);
      Append(&result, 0);
    } else if (CaseNo111(&result, &n, &index, 11, n - 15)) {
      Append(&result, 0);
      Append(&result, 1);
      Append(&result, 1);
      Append(&result, 0);
    } else if (CaseNo111(&result, &n, &index, 10, n - 14)) {
      Append(&result, 0);
      Append(&result, 1);
      Append(&result, 1);
      Append(&result, 0);
    } else {
      assert(false);
    }
  }
  return (result << n) + g_words_no_111[index];
}

static void PrintWord(unsigned n, uint64_t word) {
  assert(0 <= n && n <= 64);
  while (n-- > 0) {
    putchar('0' + ((word >> n) & 1));
  }
  putchar('\n');
}

int main(void) {
  InitTribonacci();
  InitCachedWordsNo111();
  if ((false)) {
    enum { kN = 20 };
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < g_tribonacci[kN]; i++) {
      PrintWord(kN, DecodeNo111(kN, i));
    }
  }
  uint64_t sum = 0;
  uint64_t index = 0;
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    sum += DecodeNo111(64, index % g_tribonacci[64]);
    index = (index * 2862933555777941757) + 3037000493;
  }
  return sum & 127;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand the algorithm behind this and failing due to the template madness. I'm _really_ not following that template expansion, sorry. Product of... a recursive call, 0, 1, and another recursive call? And the resulting output is also giant, so looking at the output to reverse-engineer it doesn't help either. I don't suppose you could post a slightly less optimized version with the recurrence trick without said template madness?

Comment: I am reminded why I don't like C++ that isn't 'C with `namespace` and `const` that is actually usable'.

Comment: I see the fast recurrence relation for calculating T(n) - but even my answer just straight-out stored T(n) in a lookup table, so I _don't_ see how that helps here, although it obviously does given the speedup...

Comment: @TLW reimplemented in straight C, hopefully not too much of a speed hit.

Comment: Thank you! I see the split now. By the way: I think 16 is too large - 19513x16b entries is more than an entire L1D$, at least with a 32KiB d$. Eh, easy enough to tune.

Comment: @TLW I had the same instinct, but splitting into 13s was neutral. Weird.

Comment: So if I'm groking this it's essentially a quaternary search. To generate an `N` bit output from an input in `0..T(N)`, figure out which of the 4 child cases its in, generate those two smaller pairs, and combine them. Probabilities work out. The only other remaining question there is why the magic infixes of `0` / `010` / `0110` / `0110`. It's obvious that they must be that length, and can't begin or end in `1`, but how do you determine the rest of it?

Comment: @TLW Intuitively, choose a position not too close to either end and scan in both directions to find the nearest 0s. Using (parens) to mark this position, the mutually exclusive and exhaustive possibilities are: (0), 0(1)0, 01(1)0, or 0(1)10. The strings on either side of the 0s are unrestricted 111-free.

Comment: That's clever. Thanks for the explanations!

Comment: @TLW I refactored a bit to remove the recursion and the duplication, and decreased the size of the cache since outside of microbenchmarks, there will be other code using L1.

Answer (score 1):

From [@John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman)'s comment, here's the start of an approach based on Tribonacci numbers. Basic idea:

1. Generate an unbiased number in the range `[0..T(bits))`, where `T(0) = 1, T(1) = 2, T(2) = 4, T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)`.
2. Convert to Tribonacci representation.
3. You're done.

A minimal example is as follows:

```c
// 1, 2, 4, TRIBO[n-3]+TRIBO[n-2]+TRIBO[n-1]
// possible minor perf optimization: reverse TRIBO
static const uint64_t TRIBO[65] = {1, 2, 4, 7, 13, 24, 44, 81, 149, 274, 504, 927, 1705, 3136, 5768, 10609, 19513, 35890, 66012, 121415, 223317, 410744, 755476, 1389537, 2555757, 4700770, 8646064, 15902591, 29249425, 53798080, 98950096, 181997601, 334745777, 615693474, 1132436852, 2082876103, 3831006429, 7046319384, 12960201916, 23837527729, 43844049029, 80641778674, 148323355432, 272809183135, 501774317241, 922906855808, 1697490356184, 3122171529233, 5742568741225, 10562230626642, 19426970897100, 35731770264967, 65720971788709, 120879712950776, 222332455004452, 408933139743937, 752145307699165, 1383410902447554, 2544489349890656, 4680045560037375, 8607945812375585, 15832480722303616, 29120472094716576, 53560898629395777, 98513851446415969];

// exclusive of max
extern uint64_t get_rand_64_range(uint64_t max);

uint64_t get_rand_no111(void) {
    uint64_t idx = get_rand_64_range(TRIBO[64]);
    uint64_t ret = 0;
    for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (idx >= TRIBO[i]) {
            ret |= ((uint64_t) 1) << i;
            idx -= TRIBO[i];
        }
        // optional: if (idx == 0) {break;}
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(Warning: retyped from Python code. I suggest testing.)

This satisfies the 'unbiased' portion, and is indeed faster than the naive rejection-sampling approach, but unfortunately is still pretty slow, because it's looping ~64 times.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the code below is to generate the upper 32 bits with the proper (non-uniform!) distribution, then generate the lower 32 conditional on the upper. On my laptop, it’s significantly faster than the baseline, and slightly faster than [lexicographic decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988942/2144669).

You can see the logic behind the non-uniform upper distribution with 4-bit outputs: 00 and 10 have four 2-bit lowers, 01 has three lowers, and 11 has two lowers.

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <random>

namespace {

using Generator = std::mt19937_64;

template <int bits> std::uint64_t GenerateUniform(Generator &gen) {
  static_assert(0 <= bits && bits <= 63);
  return gen() & ((std::uint64_t{1} << bits) - 1);
}

template <> std::uint64_t GenerateUniform<64>(Generator &gen) { return gen(); }

template <int bits> std::uint64_t GenerateNo111Baseline(Generator &gen) {
  std::uint64_t r;
  do {
    r = GenerateUniform<bits>(gen);
  } while (r & (r >> 1) & (r >> 2));
  return r;
}

template <int bits> struct Tribonacci {
  static constexpr std::uint64_t value = Tribonacci<bits - 1>::value +
                                         Tribonacci<bits - 2>::value +
                                         Tribonacci<bits - 3>::value;
};
template <> struct Tribonacci<0> { static constexpr std::uint64_t value = 1; };
template <> struct Tribonacci<-1> { static constexpr std::uint64_t value = 1; };
template <> struct Tribonacci<-2> { static constexpr std::uint64_t value = 0; };

template <int bits> std::uint64_t GenerateNo111(Generator &gen) {
  constexpr int upper_bits = 16;
  constexpr int lower_bits = bits - upper_bits;
  const std::uint64_t upper = GenerateNo111Baseline<upper_bits>(gen);
  for (;;) {
    if ((upper & 1) == 0) {
      return (upper << lower_bits) + GenerateNo111<lower_bits>(gen);
    }
    std::uint64_t outcome = std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint64_t>{
        0, Tribonacci<upper_bits>::value - 1}(gen);
    if ((upper & 2) == 0) {
      if (outcome < Tribonacci<upper_bits - 2>::value) {
        return (upper << lower_bits) + (std::uint64_t{1} << (lower_bits - 1)) +
               GenerateNo111<lower_bits - 2>(gen);
      }
      outcome -= Tribonacci<upper_bits - 2>::value;
    }
    if (outcome < Tribonacci<lower_bits - 1>::value) {
      return (upper << lower_bits) + GenerateNo111<lower_bits - 1>(gen);
    }
  }
}

#define BASELINE(bits)                                                         \
  template <> std::uint64_t GenerateNo111<bits>(Generator & gen) {             \
    return GenerateNo111Baseline<bits>(gen);                                   \
  }
BASELINE(0)
BASELINE(1)
BASELINE(2)
BASELINE(3)
BASELINE(4)
BASELINE(5)
BASELINE(6)
BASELINE(7)
BASELINE(8)
BASELINE(9)
BASELINE(10)
BASELINE(11)
BASELINE(12)
BASELINE(13)
BASELINE(14)
BASELINE(15)
BASELINE(16)
#undef BASELINE

static const std::uint64_t TRIBO[65] = {1,
                                        2,
                                        4,
                                        7,
                                        13,
                                        24,
                                        44,
                                        81,
                                        149,
                                        274,
                                        504,
                                        927,
                                        1705,
                                        3136,
                                        5768,
                                        10609,
                                        19513,
                                        35890,
                                        66012,
                                        121415,
                                        223317,
                                        410744,
                                        755476,
                                        1389537,
                                        2555757,
                                        4700770,
                                        8646064,
                                        15902591,
                                        29249425,
                                        53798080,
                                        98950096,
                                        181997601,
                                        334745777,
                                        615693474,
                                        1132436852,
                                        2082876103,
                                        3831006429,
                                        7046319384,
                                        12960201916,
                                        23837527729,
                                        43844049029,
                                        80641778674,
                                        148323355432,
                                        272809183135,
                                        501774317241,
                                        922906855808,
                                        1697490356184,
                                        3122171529233,
                                        5742568741225,
                                        10562230626642,
                                        19426970897100,
                                        35731770264967,
                                        65720971788709,
                                        120879712950776,
                                        222332455004452,
                                        408933139743937,
                                        752145307699165,
                                        1383410902447554,
                                        2544489349890656,
                                        4680045560037375,
                                        8607945812375585,
                                        15832480722303616,
                                        29120472094716576,
                                        53560898629395777,
                                        98513851446415969};

std::uint64_t get_rand_no111(Generator &gen) {
  std::uint64_t idx =
      std::uniform_int_distribution<std::uint64_t>{0, TRIBO[64] - 1}(gen);
  std::uint64_t ret = 0;
  for (int i = 63; i >= 0; --i) {
    if (idx >= TRIBO[i]) {
      ret |= std::uint64_t{1} << i;
      idx -= TRIBO[i];
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

} // namespace

int main() {
  Generator gen{std::random_device{}()};
  std::uint64_t sum = 0;
  for (std::int32_t i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    if constexpr (true) {
      sum += GenerateNo111<64>(gen);
    } else {
      sum += get_rand_no111(gen);
    }
  }
  return sum & 127;
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it's worth recursing further, or combining this with the answer I gave.

Comment: Of course, by the time you get to 8-bit outputs rejection sampling is 'fine' (>50% success rate)

Comment: @TLW Recursion helps, but [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74988942/2144669) is still faster for me, possibly because MT is expensive relative to the decoding logic. I have another idea that's ever so slightly biased; will let you know if I get something to work.

Comment: @TLW I did a little more optimization and now this one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

What about following simple idea:

1. Generate random `r`.
2. Find within this `r` window(s)-mask, contains 3 or more sequenced 1s.
3. If mask is 0 (no 3 or more sequenced bits) - return the `r`.
4. Substitute "incorrect" bits under that mask to new random ones.
5. Goto 2

Code sample (did not tested, compiled only):

```
uint64_t rand_no3() {
    uint64_t r, mask;
    for(r = get_rand_64() ; ; ) {
        mask  = r & (r >> 1) & (r >> 2);
        mask |= (mask << 1) | (mask << 2);
        if(mask == 0)
            return r;
        r ^= mask & get_rand_64();
    } 
}
```

Another variant of same code, with just single call `get_rand_64()`:

```
uint64_t rand_no3() {
    uint64_t r, mask = ~0ULL;
    do {
        r ^= mask & get_rand_64();
        mask  = r & (r >> 1) & (r >> 2);
        mask |= (mask << 1) | (mask << 2);
    } while(mask != 0);
    return r;
}
```

I know, the last code does not init the `r`, but it is not matter, because of this variable will be overwritten in 1st loop iteration.

Comment: > "It's useful to play around with 4-bit integers first - e.g. setting all bits involved in a conflict to random values ends up biased, and drawing out the Markov chain for 4 bits makes that obvious"

Comment: 4-bit words approach does not solve problem. Imagine, you have 2 such words: 0011,1000. Both 4-bit words are correct, but their concatenation - is not. 3-bit window spans two 4-bit words.

Comment: Nono, as in "use your suggested approach to solve the analogous problem for 4-bit words".

Comment: This approach has bias regardless of the size of the result (for >=4 at least); 4-bit words are far easier to reason about than 16b words.

Comment: It is no biased. Any bit has equal probability to be set into 0 or 1. Same as for any subset of bits for 64-bit word. For demonstrate, let we analyze algorithm for single 3-bit word. There is equal probability (7/8) to get value 000...110 as output. If generated "incorrect" 111 (1/8 probability) - then generated a new word, with equals probability also. Same you can model for another positions and block of 4,5,etc 1-bits.

Comment: It works for <= 3 bits. For >=4 bits it ends up biased due to only substituting 'incorrect' bits.

Comment: As I said in the original question: this becomes obvious once you draw out the Markov chain for 4 bits. (Or just Monte-Carlo it, for that matter.)

Answer (score -2):

You could generate the number one bit at a time, keeping track of the number of consecutive set bits. Whenever you have two consecutive set bits, you insert an unset bit and set the count back to 0.

Comment: This is biased. Easiest to see with a 3-bit output: `0b000` has a probability of 1/8 when it should be 1/7.

Comment: The first two bits have the standard probabilities, 1/4 for each combination. Only if the first two bits are 11 is a non-random 0 appended. That gives a 1/7 probability for each allowed 3 bit sequence.

Comment: It gives a biased result. Again, look at the case of `0b000`. `1/2` probability of generating `0`, then `1/2` probability of generating `0`, then `1/2` probability of generating `0`. Overall probability of generating `0b000` is `1/2*1/2*1/2`, or `1/8`. But this is wrong, as I stated previously. It should be `1/7`, not `1/8`.

Comment: There are no other ways of generating `0b000` with this approach, so the total probability of generating `0b000` is `1/8`, which is wrong.